# Not able to receive object in Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

This is my first spring sample project. Its a very basic example where I'm trying to pass firstname and lastname using Ajax to my program. But, its not able to hit the URL. Here is my code. Please let me know if anything is missing.

```
package com.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.impl.EmployeeImpl;
import com.model.Employee;

@Controller  
public class HelloWorldController { 

/*@Autowired
EmployeeImpl employee;*/

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String saveHosting(@RequestBody Employee employee) 
{
    System.out.println("First name :"+employee.getFirstname());
    System.out.println("Last name :"+employee.getLastname());
    return "hi";
}  
}
```

### My JS code

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('#click').click(function() {

    var data = {}
    data["firstname"] = $('#firstname').val();
    data["lastname"] =$('#lastname').val();
    console.log("Data :"+data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/SpringProject/hello/",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("fail");
        }
});

});

});
```

### Spring-servlet.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  
<context:component-scan  base-package="com.controller" />  

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
</bean>  

 <!--    <bean id="employee" class="com.impl.EmployeeImpl">
  <property name="firstname" value="shaik"></property>
    <property name="lastname" value="ali"></property> 
</bean> -->
</beans>
```

### POM.xml

```
         <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>SpringProject</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <msql.connector.version>5.1.10</msql.connector.version>
    <cxf.version>2.2.3</cxf.version>
    <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
    <jackson.version>2.6.3</jackson.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
       <version>4.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${msql.connector.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId> <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId> 
        <version>2.3</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
```

src
    
      
        maven-compiler-plugin
        3.1
        
          1.7
          1.7
        
      
      
        maven-war-plugin
        2.3
        
          WebContent
          false

### Web.xml

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>SpringProject</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>   
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

 <!-- <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/lib/soapservice-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param> -->

<!--    <listener>
    <listener-  class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

### Error

```
jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:8080/SpringProject/hello/ 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Enable spring logs, and check cotrollers to url mapping. Make sure it's `SpringProject/hello`

Comment: @SergheyBishyr, can you explain me how to enable spring logs?

Comment: remove the slash at end of the url

Comment: @SergheyBishyr, if I give SpringProject/hello, its overriding the URL as http://localhost:8080/SpringProject/SpringProject/hello

Comment: @Jaiwo99, tried with that.. Same reply http://localhost:8080/SpringProject/hello 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What about web.xml, it may have some mistake ?

Comment: @nikeshjoshi.. Updated with web.xml

Comment: Your servlet only handles `*.htm` whereas it should handle `/*` your request never reaches anything.

Comment: @Syed just add spring package to your logging configuration (i.e. log4j.xml) and set level to debbug

Comment: /SpringProject/hello.htm use this url

Comment: @nikeshjoshi this won't help at all. It's not a URL mapped to the cotroller.

Comment: It is mapped to the dispatcher servlet , so it will work.

Comment: @SergheyBishyr, in which like should I add the level debug?, because first of all its not hitting the controller

Comment: @Syed if you are using log4j than you need something like this `<Logger name="org.springframework" level="debug">`

Comment: @Serghey Bishyr, Should I add that under web.xml? In addition to log, what should be written?

Comment: No, it's not a web.xml configuration. It won't fix the problem, it can give you a clue on what is the problem. Do you use any logging framework?

Comment: I have included log4j in the dependency.. So that can be used for logging. But, my question is, as its not hitting the class, whats the use of it?

Answer (score 0):

Update your servlet mapping as  (in web.xml)

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Now, I'm not able to load the index.jsp itself.. HTTP Status 404 -

Comment: If you are not able to load index, it means tomcat container i.e. servlet container is not able to parse your web.xml , check your tomcat console you will find some exception like : SAX:PARSER Exception at some line no....

Comment: No nikesh.. There is no such error..There is a red color cross mark on the project, but there are no such errors in the project. I have cleaned the project and made maven build too